# Create a function to get values in a line in C#

Tags: c#, readline

I have a text file as follows:

```
NPSER   NASER   NQSER
10  5   3
JPNM    EPNS    RNPS
12  10  11
ACBE    MNEF    QPNS
25  11  78
```

This is a simplified data from my long data. I want to automatically find the values of NPSER, NASER, NQSER and so forth.

So far my code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace read_file
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TextReader namefile = new StreamReader(@"E:\Code in C Sharp\read-file\read-file\test.txt");
            string line = namefile.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            Console.ReadLine();

            ////Read second line
            string line1 = namefile.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static public string[] Returnval(string line)
        {
            var Returnval = line.Split('\t');
            return Returnval;
        }
    }   
}
```

I have created a function Returnval which splits the string which are tab separated. I want to modify this function which would automatically take new line as input and then I should be able to use the function like this:

```
Returnval(NPSER, NASER, NQSER)
```

I tried to add a new line to Returnval function which is as follows:

```
string line = namefile.Readline();
```

I got an error saying namefile is not in context.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to pass namefile to your function.

Comment: namefile is defined in your Main function and you're trying to access it in Returnval function. You can pass `namefile` as parameter to Returnval.

Comment: You have quite a few problems as far as I can see. Most problematic is perhaps that you seem to think NPSER can be used as a variable name, just because it was read as a data string. C# does not support that kind of programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jdbaba,

If I understand your question correctly, you are having a variable scope issue. Since you declared namefile within the Main method, it will only be available within that method. If you want to access it within another method, you will need to declare it outside the Main Method as follows:

```
public static TextReader _namefile;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _namefile = new StreamReader(@"E:\Code in C Sharp\read-file\read-file\test.txt");
    string line = _namefile.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    Console.ReadLine();

    ////Read second line
    string line1 = _namefile.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(line1);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static public string[] Returnval(string line)
{
    string line1 = _namefile.ReadLine();
    var Returnval = line.Split('\t');
    return Returnval;
}
```

It's usually better practice to pass the object as a parameter to the second method like

```
Returnval(namefile, NPSER, NASER, NQSER)
```

, but declaring namefile as a public static variable works well for your test project.

Good Luck!

Comment: StreamReader should be in a "using" so it gets disposed.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `TextReader` as a parameter to your function, as follows:

```
public static string[] Returnval(TextReader nameFile, string a, string b, string c)
{
    string line = nameFile.ReadLine();
    //All your other code
}
```

And then from main you can call it as follow, passing your StreamReader:

```
Returnval(nameFile, NPSER, NASER, NQSER);
```

Note that reading a line containing `NPSER, NASER, NQSER` doesn't automatically create those variabels for you. Since they're all string, however, you could probably modify your function again to be:

```
public static string[] Returnval(TextReader nameFile, string[] myStrings)
{
    string line = nameFile.ReadLine();
    //All your other code
}
```

And then call it from main using:

```
Returnval(nameFile, line.Split('\t');
```

Where the string `line` contains `NPSER, NASER, NQSER` separated by tabs.